# PyQt5, (MacOS) how to return filenames and paths from subclassed QFileDialog without using exec?

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm using the feature incorrectly.

I want to make a MacOS style sheet window, and I've subclassed QFileDialog in order to set WindowModality and Parent.

If I await user confirmation with `if diag.exec():` I can obtain the selected files, BUT, the sheet window is completely misplaced (i.e. not appearing from where it should)

[image]

If I instead use `if diag.open():` the sheet displays as it should, but I don't seem to get any filenames or paths returned.

Am I doing something wrong, or does this happen to be broken?

Example code:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText("CLICK ME")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test)


    def test(self):
        diag = OpenSheet()
        if diag.exec(): # Replace with diag.open() to prevent weird bug, but doesn't return any filenames now
            fileNames = diag.selectedFiles()
            print(fileNames)

class OpenSheet(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowModality(True)
        self.setParent(mainwindow)
        self.setFileMode(self.ExistingFiles)
        self.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
    mainwindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton    = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText("CLICK ME")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.test)

    def test(self):
        diag = OpenSheet()
        #if diag.exec(): # Replace with diag.open() to prevent weird bug, but doesn't return any filenames now
        #    fileNames = diag.selectedFiles()
        #    print("\n", fileNames)
        options = diag.Options()
        options |= diag.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = diag.getOpenFileNames(None, "diag.getOpenFileNames()", "",
                                        "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if files:
            print("Selected files: ", files)        


class OpenSheet(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowModality(True)
        self.setParent(mainwindow)
        self.setFileMode(self.ExistingFiles)
        self.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Returns a very non-native dialog though, which is kind of the diametric opposite :(